# Pycharm remote repo name

Tags: git, pycharm

I am workin with Pycharm and I have Git repo with two remotes called `github` and `heroku`. Yes, I have not remote called `origin`. Now I want to be able pull/push from/to both remotes. Where could I specify remote names?

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 4.0, you can choose the remote name to push into by clicking on the name of the remote in the Push Commits dialog:

[image: Push Commits screenshot]

The Pull Changes dialog (Git | Repository | Pull...) also allows you to choose the remote to pull from. Note that the default "Update project" dialog pulls from the remote specified in the tracking branch for your local branch.